Any idea what "Vietnamese IM" folder is?
I have been browsing through my Mac user Library folder while trying to locate my FCPX assets and stumbled upon this folder (screenshot).
It is named Vietnamese IM and the folder content seems like a shortcut to my user.
FYI I am not Vietnamese, I do not speak Vietnamese and there's no chance I accidentally set my Mac to display in Vietnamese so this folder seems a little out of place and suspect.
Can anyone explain please?


Sounds like Vietnamese 'Input Method'.  Do you have any keyboard utilities like 'UniKey' installed?

I have the same thing.  I assume it is part of Apple's Vietnamese input methods, which I have used a few times.

Yes, I have it, too, though I also have never used it. A total of 12Kb.

Running "Get Info" (Cmd+I) on this directory shows

Indicating that this directory belongs to an input method provided as part of macOS.
There are similar folders for Apple's Chinese, Japanese, and Korean IM's.
